# Flutter - map two lists in one request

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm passing the mapped list (firstList) to Widget (as a model) and I'd like to pass a second one as a regionModel. So here's my question. Is it possible to map two lists in one request (need to map secondList and pass it as regionModel: value2). I found something like IterableZip but it's not supported anymore.

```
Widget _buildView(
    List<FirstListModels> firstList,
    List<SecondListModels> secondList,

... 
children: firstList.map((value) {
              return Widget(
                  model: value, regionModel: value2);
            }).toList()
```

then when i pass them I have:

```
class SomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirstListModel model;
  final List<SecondListModel> regionModel;
```

So, i need to get rid of list to have only SecondListModel and have output like this:

```
class SomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirstListModel model;
  final SecondListModel regionModel;
```

Comment: `IterableZip` is well supported, try `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sovled

I left it like it was and then i compare both model and list with firstWhere and return string from it (part of url)

```
String _compareLists(){
  var result = widget.secondList.firstWhere(
    (element) => element?.property == widget.firstList.property, orElse: () => null)
    .?propertyContainsUrl ?? "";


    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both lists have the same length, you can use `for` loop and `spread operator`

```dart
void main() {
  final firstList = ['firstList - item #1', 'firstList - item #2'];
  final secondList = ['secondList - item #1', 'secondList - item #2'];

  final listOfModels = [
    for (var i = 0; i < firstList.length; i++) ...{
      SomeModel(model: firstList[i], region: secondList[i]),
    }
  ];

  print(listOfModels);
}

class SomeModel {
  final String model;
  final String region;
  SomeModel({this.model, this.region});

  toString() => 'SomeModel(model: $model, region: $region)';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately they don't and I need to find solution which let me pass both in one same request. I've tried IterableZip but it's not helpful at all.

Comment: @P-Jag, so how both lists are related? What you want to do when first list is shorter or when second one is shorter?

Comment: Both lists store models, and I need to pass it to Widget (which is created on base of firstList) and than compare one property and display photo from second one). I hope is not that confusing at it seems.

Comment: It is a little bit. Please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question to prevent future misunderstandings.